# Using 2 scanf("%[^\n]s") but the second one is getting skipped

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
int main(){

     char str1[20], str2[20];
    printf("Enter string 1 : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",str1);

    printf("Enter string 2 : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",str2);

    printf("String 1 is %s\n",str1);
    printf("String 2 is %s\n",str2);
    removeFromSecond(str1,str2);
}
```

The output is :

```
Enter string 1 : in

Enter string 2 : String 1 is in

String 2 is ■   a
```

It's just not asking to enter the second string.
I can't remember, but I've read somewhere that there is a line we need to add to eat up all unused '\n's.
Please, if anyone knows that, I need exactly that line.

Comment: The _unused_ `\n` from the first input, is used to terminate the second input.

Comment: Why do you have `s` at the end of each format string?

Comment: If you want to read a line of input, use `fgets()`, not `scanf()`.

Comment: The `&` befor `str1` and `str2` is also incorrect.

Comment: My opinion, but: `scanf` is a primitive tool.  It's only good for simple input.  `%[]` is not a simple format string.  If you find yourself wanting to use `%[]`, it probably means you're doing something fancy enough that you should be [moving beyond `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537) and using something else, perhaps `fgets`.  Or if you'd rather keep using `scanf` for now, limit yourself to `%d`, `%f`, and `%s`.  All the rest are just too much trouble.

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]", str2);` note the added space before `%` (to consume the previous newline), and the removed `s` (a beginner's mistake).

Comment: @WeatherVane `gets()` is a better alternative than `scanf(" %[^\n]", ...`.  Yet both are not used in quality code.

Comment: You may want to read this: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: @chux true, I overlooked a length restriction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, use fgets() as everyone is telling me to because it is the right choice. But still if anyone wants to know the answer for what I actually asked, it is as weather-vane said in comments It's a rookie's mistake, just add a space before the % in the second scanf.

Like scanf("%[^\n]", str2); -> to -> scanf(" %[^\n]", str2);

Comment: And as @chux pointed out you need a length restriction. `scanf(" %19[^\n]", str2);`

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]", str2);` reads all leading white-space - 0 or more.  Input like `"\n"` will block until more input.  Leading spaces will not get saved, yet internal and trailing non-\n spaces will get saved. Input like `"\n\n\n123\n"` will skip 3 lines.  `scanf(" %[^\n]", str2);` is not a good solution to read a _line_.

Answer (score 1):

2nd `scanf("%[^\n]s",str2);` fails to save anything as the previous line's `'\n'` was not consumed by the prior `scanf("%[^\n]s",str1);` nor this `scanf("%[^\n]s",str2);`.

To read a *line* of user input use `fgets()`.

```
// scanf("%[^\n]s",str1);
fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin);
```

As `fgets()` also reads and saves a potential `'\n'`, use below to lop it off if it is there.

```
str1[strcspn(str1, "\n")] = 0;
```

---

`scanf()` is rarely as good choice.  Do not use until you understand why it is bad.

---

If you _must use `scanf()`, drop the useless `s` in the format, add a *width*:

```
// Ugly POS code
char str1[20] = "";  // Set to empty string in case nothing saved
// Read up to 19 non-\n characters.  If more available, read them but don't save.
scanf("%19[^\n]%*[^\n]",str1);  
// consume up to 1 trailing \n, do not save.
scanf("%*1[\n]");

// TBD check return values.
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using scanf because I have an online interview next week and I don't know what compiler they will b using. I heard gets doesn't work in some compilers, and I've never used fgets and I thought it might fail just like gets.

Comment: @HimanshuRai `gets()` is [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) because it lacks a width limit and is not standard since C11.  `fgets()` accepts a _size_ to prevent overfilling.